# What should the error statements be for exit 3 and 4 in my c++ simple buffer code?

Tags: c++, c++11, error-handling, c++14, buffer

I need to input error statements above exits three and four and then actually force the code to go to these error statements so I can have screenshot proof that they are working. However, I can't quite work out what should be in each. My initial thoughts are 'the output file can't be created for 3 and 'The file you want to read from is empty' for 4, but I can't seem to trigger these errors so I feel like that's not correct.

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#define BUF_SIZE 500
#define OUTPUT_MODE 0700


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int in_file, out_file;
    int read_size = 1, write_size;
    char buf[BUF_SIZE];
    if (argc != 3){ 
        cout<<"The command-line input does not contain 3 arguments"<<endl;
        exit(1);
        }
     in_file= open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
     if (in_file  < 0) {
        cout<<"The file you are trying to copy from doesnt exist"<<endl;
        exit(2);
        }
    out_file = creat(argv[2], OUTPUT_MODE);
    if (out_file < 0) {
        cout<<"Error statement 3"<<endl;
            exit(3);
        }
    while (read_size > 0) {
            read_size = read(in_file, buf, BUF_SIZE);
            if (read_size <0){
            cout<<"Error statement 4"<<endl;
                exit(4);
            }
            write_size = write(out_file, buf, read_size);
            if (write_size<=0){
                close(in_file);
                close(out_file);
                cout<<"Reading and writing from and to files is complete"<<endl;
                exit(5);
               }
             }
}
```

Comment: The value of `argc` is the number of valid elements in `argv`, it's not the number of arguments. For example, if three arguments is provided then the number of valid elements will be *four*, `argv[0]` (the command name) then `argv[1]` to `argv[3]` for the actual arguments.

Comment: thanks, that part is working fine already for what i need it to do

Comment: How do you try to trigger it? How do you call the program? From a shell? With what parameters?

Comment: If `creat` or `read` fail, they set errno  to tell you why.  Create an error message that contains the path used to open the file and the string in `strerror(errno)`.  (Do not call any functions that may modify errno before you call `strerror`)

Answer (score 0):

The way to work out how these functions can /will fail, is to read the documentation for them.

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html
https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html

(note, the documentation of creat says its equivalent to calling open with specific arguments)

At the bottom, it lists what errno will be set to and why.
Open, for example, will fail on a read only disk.

Answer (score 0):

Most standard library functions will set errno to give you the reason they failed.  Use that information, and write your error messages to stderr:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#define OUTPUT_MODE 0700

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        int in_file, out_file;
        int read_size, write_size;
        char buf[BUFSIZ];
        if (argc != 3){
                cerr << "Missing arguments" <<endl;
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        in_file= open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
        if( in_file < 0 ){
                cerr << argv[1] << ": " << strerror(errno) << endl;
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        out_file = creat(argv[2], OUTPUT_MODE);
        if( out_file < 0 ){
                cerr << argv[2] << ": " << strerror(errno) << endl;
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        while( (read_size = read(in_file, buf, BUFSIZ)) > 0 ){
                const char *s = buf;
                do {
                        write_size = write(out_file, s, read_size);
                        read_size -= write_size;
                        if( write_size <= 0 ){
                                cerr << argv[2] << ": " << strerror(errno) << endl;
                                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                        }
                        s += write_size;
                } while( read_size > 0);
        }
        if( read_size < 0 ){
                cerr << argv[1] << ": " << strerror(errno) << endl;
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        close(in_file);
        close(out_file);
}
```